# how to print last few lines when a pattern is matched using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to last few lines when a pattern is matched in a file using sed.
if file has following entries:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the forth line.
This is the Last line.
```

so, search for pattern, "Last" and print last few lines ..

Answer (score 0):

Find 'Last' using sed and pipe it to tail command which print last n lines of the file -n specifies the no. of lines to be read from end of the file, here I am reading last 2 lines of the file.

```
sed '/Last/ p' yourfile.txt|tail -n 2
```

For more info on tail use `man tail`.

Also, `|` symbol here is known as a pipe(unnamed pipe), which helps in inter-process communication. So, in simple words `sed` feeds data to `tail` command using pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "find the pattern and also print the *previous* few lines". `grep` is your friend: to print the previous 3 lines:

```
$ grep -B 3 "Last" file
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the forth line.
This is the Last line.
```

`-B n` for "before". There's also `-A n` ("after"), and `-C n` ("context", both before and after).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/2;Ta};/Last/P;D' file
```

This will print the line containing `Last` and the two previous lines.

N.B. This will only print the lines before the match once. Also more lines can by shown by changing the `2` to however many lines you want.